# T-SQL query to get # of something for a given category, via lookup table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've got three tables, two are "data" tables, one is a join (or lookup) table.

**Place Table**

- PlaceId
- Name
- etc...

**Categories Table**

- CatId
- Name
- etc...

**PlaceCats Table**

- PlaceId
- CatId

(with appropriate relationships defined between each Id field)

What I want to do is pull the categories that contain less than 5 Places... for some reason I just can wrap my mind around the T-SQL to make that happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Categories 
WHERE CatId IN 
(
    SELECT CatId  
    FROM PlaceCats
    GROUP BY CatId
    HAVING COUNT(*) < 5
)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the raw data:

`select CatID, count(*)
from PlaceCats
group by CatID
having count(*) < 5`